# Postgresql function with if statement

Tags: postgresql, function

How can I make this pseudo code to work in Postgresql:

```
create or replace function getf(arg character varying(255)) returns int
as $$
if arg = 'a' then return 1;
else return 2;
$$ language sql;
```

Based on argument I need to return some values and there is no other table I need to query. Just need to build a logic inside function.
Tried to replace if with when clause, but could not figure out how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: you are using sql language, and for it [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) you can find the right [IF THEN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) statement instruction

Comment: @Patrick's answer is good. But notice that most of the times you do not need procedural code. Post the real problem and you may be surprised with the answers.

Comment: In this case I had to create derived table and in case when certain fields where having certain values create specific status code (pure business logic based on incoming values returning some status).

Comment: That "business logic" can probably be implemented using an `EXISTS()` in the query, or even a lookup table. Functions are costly, see the `immutable strict` options+remark in @Tometzky 's answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
create or replace function getf(arg character varying(255)) returns int as $$
begin
  if arg = 'a' then
    return 1;
  else 
    return 2;
  end if;
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

Note that this is a PL/pgSQL function.

The online manual has an excellent chapter on [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html). That should provide everything you need to get started writing procedural function with ample support for logical branching.

Answer (score 5):

Using `sql` language, you can do it using [case when](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html):

```
create or replace function getf(arg character varying(255)) returns int as
 $$

select case 
        when arg = 'a' 
         then 1
         else 2 
       end

$$ language sql;
```

Comment: I get an error: ERROR:  column "arg" does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

A pure SQL function. It is ugly, because SQL does not have `IF`. (you could use `CASE` instead, which is ugly, too) The `DISTINCT FROM` is needed to catch NULLs.

```
DROP function getf(_arg character varying(255) );
create or replace function getf(_arg character varying(255)) returns INTEGER
as $$
        SELECT 1::integer
        WHERE  _arg = 'a'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2::integer
        WHERE  _arg IS DISTINCT FROM 'a'
        ;
$$ language sql;

SELECT getf( 'a' );
SELECT getf( 'b' );
SELECT getf( NULL );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
create function getf(arg text) returns int
immutable strict language sql as $$
  select case 
    when arg = 'a' 
      then 1
      else 2 
    end
$$;
```

This is almost like Houari's answer, but:

- it uses `text` as argument type — there's no point in limiting argument length in Postgres, in which there's no difference in representation;
- it is `immutable`, so a database can cache it's result from the same argument, which can be faster;
- it is `strict`, so it would not be run on NULL values and simply return NULL, as it's probably a programming error for it to be used on a NULL value anyway, and it could mask this error and make it harder to debug if it would return 2 for NULL.